# Bottomsheet acting strange with windowsoftinputmode=adjustResize kotlin compose

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-softkeyboard, bottom-sheet, window-soft-input-mode

Bottomsheet acting strange with windowsoftinputmode=adjustResize kotlin compose.

I added `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in manifest file in order to solve something. Unfortunately, the text fields inside BottomSheetScaffold are not working right, **when the keyboard is open, the screen goes crazy.**

***video:***
[Video Link](https://streamable.com/ltyrlt)